# Convert the computed amplitude of a complex bin back to its complex form

Tags: signal-processing, fft, complex-numbers

I am working a dsp algorithm where I take the FFT of a time domain signal, compute the amplitudes of each bin using  `sqrt(real * real + imaginary * imaginary)`  and then modify the amplitude. How do I convert the modified amplitude back into the complex domain so that i can run the IFFT and recover the processed time domain signal?

Comment: Are you looking for (x+iy)/|(x+iy)| * newAmplitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would most likely want to retain the phase and use this to reconstruct the new bin value. What you're effectively doing is modifying a complex number in polar form, i.e. changing the magnitude but retaining the phase:

```
mag = sqrt(re^2 + im^2)  ; convert re, im to polar (mag, phi)
phi = atan2(im, re)

mag = mag * scale        ; apply factor `scale` to magnitude

re = mag * cos(phi)      ; convert new mag, phi back to re, im
im = mag * sin(phi)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I kept looking at points on the complex plane knowing that since I know the angle, I can somehow increase the magnitude and map it back using the angle. Putting it in polar form was the piece I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea why, when running the code with this applied, there is a noticeable 'blip' between my fft windows?

Comment: Are you using a suitable method to do your frequency domain processing, e.g. overlap-add or overlap-save ?